# Java - dynamically change logging level

Tags: java, logging

I would like to be able to tell the JVM to stop logging certain level of messages at some point in the execution chain. At some point I want to only log messages with `SEVERE` level, so I was thinking of doing this:

```
    for(Enumeration<String> loggerNames = logManager.getLoggerNames(); loggerNames.hasMoreElements();){
        String name = loggerNames.nextElement();
        Logger nextLogger = logManager.getLogger(name);
        if(nextLogger != null)
            nextLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same logic i.e. set a global variable that would stop printing to log unless SEVERE? I need to distinguish between Console output (in test) and file output in live, so I could potentially set these level on the handler (console and File)?

Comment: I think you need a java logging properties files.
Check this http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143

Comment: No, I want to use DYNAMIC changes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION:

This is exactly what I needed:

```
Handler[] handlers =
  Logger.getLogger( "" ).getHandlers();
for ( int index = 0; index < handlers.length; index++ ) {
  handlers[index].setLevel( Level.SEVERE);
}
```

Comment: That worked for me too. The advantage of this pure java approach is that I can do it in groovy too, when libraries have too much logging at the default level (I'm looking at you Apache SSHD).

Answer (score 2):

To control you application configuration dynamically, a common way is to use JMX.

JConsole, part of the jdk, allows you to control MBeans manually but you could also access them programatically.

You can use JMX to control MBeans as described in [this page](http://www.jroller.com/ray/entry/managing_log4j_logging_levels_for).

Answer (score 0):

With log4j you can change the level of the root logger.

This may work:

```
logManager.getLogger( "" ).setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

or use `Logger.getParent()` to find the root logger