# Is it possible to override values set in properties file for java.util.logging programatically?

Tags: java, properties-file, java.util.logging

I have an application for which I want to have the logging level set to `INFO` unless Debug Mode is set in which case I want to set the level to `FINEST`.

If I set the level in the properties file it does not get overridden from the program using `logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST)` also, if I do not set anything for the `.level` field in the properties file, by default the INFO level is taken and again I cannot override to use `FINEST` if isDebugEnable().

How can I make this level configurable based on the condition ?

```
 try(InputStream configFile = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties")) {
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to load default logging properties.", e);
    }
 if (isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
    } else {
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }
```

My config file is as follows:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO

# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

# Enable console to set level to FINEST and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I can do this using as follow, but would like to know if there is a better way to do this. (May be using properties file)

```
ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
setLogLevel();
consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
logger.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - dynamically change logging level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760095/java-dynamically-change-logging-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting a `DEBUG` option before startup of the JVM then just package a 2nd `logging.properties` file called `debug.properties` and change the `java.util.logging.config.file` to point to the `debug.properties` when you want debug options.

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= FINEST

# default file output is in user's home directory.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

# Enable console to set level to show all levels.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

If you have to set the levels at runtime you'll run in to problems with [readConfiguration not resetting all everything after boot of the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441467/use-of-readconfiguration-method-in-logging-activities/36069135#36069135).  Under JDK 8 or older all you can do is call `readConfiguration` to populate the defaults and add more code to fix the broken behavior.  Since you just need to set the level on handlers then just add that code.

```
try(InputStream configFile = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties")) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to load default logging properties.", e);
}

Level lvl;
if (isDebugEnabled()) {
    lvl = Level.FINEST;
} else {
    lvl = Level.INFO;
}
logger.setLevel(lvl);
for(Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
    h.setLevel(lvl);
}
```

JDK 9 provides an `updateConfiguration` method that will work around the broken behavior of the `readConfiguration` method.